# can not find element to click on it for below angular code in protracror

Tags: javascript, jquery, protractor

Can anyone suggest me how to get an element and how to click on it by using below code

```html
<span class="referFriendsClass">
    <p-menu class="refereFrnd" #refereFrndMenu popup="popup" [model]="items"></p-menu>
    <button #btn type="button" class="refereFrnd"  (click)="refereFrndMenu.toggle($event)"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></button>
</span>
```

I have tried with below code but getting error

```js
let footer = element(by.css('div[class="ui-g"]'));
footer.element(by.tagName('i')).click();
```

> Error: Failed: unknown error: Element <i _ngcontent-c1="" class="fa fa-user"></i> is not clickable at point (1079, 52). Other element would receive the click: <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="modal-content">...</div>
>       (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.94)
>       (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)

Comment: are you using angular?

Comment: That error is saying you have a modal (`.modal-content`) on top of the element.  Depends what exactly that is, but if its like most modals you probably need to close it before interacting with other elements on the page

Answer (score 0):

You should use expected conditions (http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions):

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var footer = element(by.css('div[class="ui-g"]'));
var isDisplayed = EC.visibilityOf(footer);

...

browser.wait(isDisplayed, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You get an error `Other element would receive the click: <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="modal-content">...</div>`

It means that element that you want to select is hidden behind the `.modal-content`. Probably some modal window appears on the page, so your element is not visible.

Moreover you need to remember that, by default Protractor (as Selenium) try to click at the centre of the selected element. So even if the part of element is visible on page, there might be a case that the centre of this button is overlaid.